# Cookies to hide multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, uniqueidentifier

I am trying to hide random multiple elements, so what I have done was given each a unique ID.

```
$(function() {
  var left= $('#left'),
      right = $('#right'),
      heads = $('.maintitle'),
      i,
      leftHead = $(left).find(heads),
      rightHead = $(right).find(heads);
        $(leftHead).prepend('<div class="close"></div>');
        $(rightHead).prepend('<div class="close"></div>');
      var close = $('.close'),
      Lnumber = $('#left .module'),
      Rnumber =$('#right .module');
          for (i=0;i<Lnumber.length;i++) {
               $(Lnumber)[i].id='widg'+i; 
               }
       close.click(function() {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
            $(this).parent().parent().slideUp().addClass('hidden');
            SetCookie('hidden'+id,"true",100);
            });
      var cookieId = $('#left .module');
           for (i=0;i<cookieId.length;i++) {
             var newArray = [cookieId[i].id];
           if (ReadCookie(newArray) == 'true') {
               var cName = newArray.replace('hidden','');
               alert(cName);
              }
            }  
        });
```

As you can see in the ReadCookie function I have it alerting the ID's that are hidden, though this doesn't work either yet. I am brand new to Cookies and just having a hard time getting this to work correctly.

Here are the functions for the cookies...

```
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
var today = new Date();
var expire = new Date();
if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*nDays);
document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
    + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString(),';path = /';
 }

function KillCookie(cookieName) {
    SetCookie(cookieName,"", - 1);
 }

function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
  var theCookie=""+document.cookie;
  var ind=theCookie.indexOf(cookieName+"=");
  if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
  var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind);
  if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
  return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+1,ind1));
  }
```

If anyone sees any other way to do this that is fine, just need to get the specific ID's to make sure they stay hidden when clicked and changing pages.

Comment: Look at this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062600/use-jquery-cookies-in-showing-hiding-elements-jquery?rq=1

Comment: The question at hand is not the cookies, as I won't use jQuery cookies when javascript clearly does the job. the question at hand is how to create the multiple arrays without assigning and reading the specific cookie manually instead dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the jQuery Cookie plugin?

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Then create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Then to read the cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => "the_value"
```